# How to close a shelled application

Tags: vba

I ran the following VBA code (in MS Word) in order to start Windows Calculator and perform some computations:

```
Dim RetVal, i
RetVal = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\CALC.EXE", 1)    ' Run Calculator.
```

The code does some calculations and I input the information into a popup box.  After I hit enter, the program automatically does some magical formatting and prints a form (I have no problems with that).

However, I can't figure out how to simply close the calculator that I just opened.  I don't need it to test how many instances are open or whatever.  Just close it. How to close an application I've shelled?

Edit: here's most of the macro:

```
Sub PageHeight()

Dim ReturnValue, i
ReturnValue = Shell("calc.exe", 1)

ActiveDocument.PageSetup.PageWidth = InchesToPoints(InputBox("Enter Page Width - 8.5 inches or less" & vbNewLine & "Do not enter the inches symbol.", xpos:=1440, ypos:=720))  
    ActivePrinter = "HP LaserJet P2055dn UPD PCL 6"

With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
        .PrintOut Background:=False
        .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
End With

    End
```

Comment: It would help if you'd add some of the code you use to do the calculations so that people can see how it's interacting with the shelled application. You can use the [edit] tag below the question to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - Stop running program that was started by Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1800066/11683)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - Stop running program that was started by Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800066/excel-vba-stop-running-program-that-was-started-by-shell)